# What is an ECMAScript "native object"?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-5

According to the [ECMA-262](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm) a native object

> object in an ECMAScript implementation whose semantics are fully
>   defined by this specification rather than by the host environment

A built-in object is defined as

> object supplied by an ECMAScript implementation, independent of the
>   host environment, that is present at the start of the execution of an
>   ECMAScript program.

with a note

> Standard built-in objects are defined in this specification, and *an
>   ECMAScript implementation may specify and define others*.  **Every
>   built-in object is a native object.**

If a native object is fully defined by the ECMA-262 specification rather than the host environment and an ECMAScript implementation may specify and define new built-in objects, how is it that these new built-in object's can be native objects when they are not fully defined by the ECMA-262 specification?

What am I missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They're "native" because they come with the ECMAScript *implementation*.  A host environment in generally an application consisting of an ECMAScript implementation and several other interfaces that work together.  For instance,

- **Web Browser** — a host environment consisting of ECMAScript implementation, DOM interface, Rendering engine, UI, etc.
- **Windows Script Host** — a host environment consisting of ECMAScript implementation, VBScript implementation, etc.
- **Node.js** — a host environment consisting of ECMAScript implementation (V8), HTTP interfaces, etc.

"Built-in" objects are *required* to inherit from `Object` or `Function`, whereas *host objects* — objects provided by the host environment, but not necessarily present at the start of execution — are not required to but may (and sometimes do).

#### Examples of native objects defined by ECMA-262

- `Object()`, `Array()`, `Date()`
- `Math`, `JSON`, the Global object.

#### Examples of native, built-in objects *not* defined by ECMA-262

- Mozilla's numerous JavaScript extensions — such as [`WeakMap()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/WeakMap) or [`__proto__`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/Proto)
- JScript's [`ActiveXObject()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7sw4ddf8(v=VS.85).aspx) constructor and (undocumented) [`CollectGarbage()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1614662/what-is-the-javascript-method-collectgarbage-when-and-why-should-it-be-used) function

#### Examples of host objects

- DOM objects, `document` and `window`
- `console`

Comment: Are you sure there are no built-in objects whom `Object.getPrototypeOf(obj)` doesn't contain `Object.prototype` ?

Comment: Note that WeakMap isn't a proprietary extension, it's an implementation of a Harmony proposal. Also `ActiveXObject()` is a host object and not a native object.

Comment: @gsnedders: `ActiveXObject()` *is* a native object, but it returns a host object.  Even in older versions of IE and JScript, `ActiveXObject.prototype` is present whereas it is not on *all other* host objects.  Also, `WeakMap()` is an extension until Harmony becomes ES 6 :-p

Comment: @Raynos: I can't say for sure, but I believe that it would be a violation of the spec.  Built-in objects are required to be native and therefore following the semantics laid out by ECMA-262.

Comment: @gsnedders can one argue it is proprietary because it may differ from the finalized ES6 specification semantics of `WeakMap` ?

Comment: @AndyE Whether or not the object has a `prototype` property doesn't change whether it is a host object or a native object. Try using a custom impl of [[Construct]] matching that of native objects, for example --- that won't work, so its semantics aren't entirely described by ES.

Comment: @Raynos @AndyE `Object.getPrototypeOf(Object.prototype) === null`. The `Object` prototype object is the only built-in which doesn't have the `Object` prototype object in its prototype chain.

Comment: @Raynos It's not proprietary because it's sufficently specified to be implemented by anyone. It's not standard, true, but it's not proprietary.

Comment: @gsnedders: word *'proprietary'* retracted.  My argument wasn't that `ActiveXObject` was a built-in object because it has a `prototype`, but rather that having a `prototype` in environments whose host objects don't have one is evidence that it's provided by the JavaScript implementation (JScript) and not the host environment.

Comment: @AndyE I think that line between JScript and host environment is implementation specific. My understanding is that (ignoring the JIT) everything is translated from js source code into C++ objects. Some implement more javascript object like interfaces then others. having a split between JScript objects or host objects is strange.

Comment: @AndyE  I think, `window` is a native object, not a host object. I have created [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10553188/425275).

Answer (score 2):

The *semantics* of a native object are fully defined by ECMA-262. The object itself may not be.

So we have three levels of objects:

1. **Standard built-in objects**: defined ECMA-262, and follow ECMA-262 semantics. Example: `Object`.
2. **Other built-in objects**: not defined in ECMA-262, but follow ECMA-262 semantics. Example: `setTimeout`.
3. **Host objects**: don't follow ECMA-262 semantics; they can have weird behavior of any sort, and interact with EMCA-262 built-in objects in weird and unexpected ways (for example lying about various internal properties). Example: `NodeList`.

Comment: `setTimeout` isn't a built-in object, it's a host object (it's part of the DOM).

Comment: I'm not entierly clear myself, but I am pretty sure it follows ECMA-262 semantics, which would make it a built-in by these definitions, right?

Comment: host objects can follow ECMA-262 semantics if they want to.  Sadly, in older versions of IE and other browsers, this isn't the case.  Even `setTimeout instanceof Function` returns `false` and `typeof setTimeout` returns `"object"` in IE 7 and lower.

Answer (score 0):

The definition of `native object` is the relative term of `host object`
Like `window.console` object is a host object which Ecma262 haven't been documented to tell the browser how to implement it.
And Ecma262 is just a project to specify the language the feature. ECMAScript implementation actually is browser's business. That means the implementation compliant to the specification on the `object type`, we can say it `built-in object` though they does not work exactly the same.