# In ECMAScript, how are some of native objects also built-in?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-5

I suppose a definition of native and built-in objects is required to answer this question. Here's what the ECMAScript spec defines these as:

> 4.3.6 native object
>
> object in an ECMAScript implementation, independent of the host environment, that is present at the start of
>   the execution of an ECMAScript program.
>
> NOTE   Standard native built-in objects are defined in this
>   specification. **Some native objects are built-in**; others may be
>   constructed during the course of execution of an ECMAScript program
>
> 4.3.7 built-in object
>
> object supplied by an ECMAScript implementation, independent of the host environment, that is present
>   at the start of the execution of an ECMAScript program
>
> NOTE   Standard built-in objects are defined in this specification,
>   and an ECMAScript implementation may specify and define others. Every
>   built-in object is a native object. A *built-in constructor* is a
>   built-in object that is also a constructor.

I'm looking forward to an explanation of this one.

Comment: I suppose "ruing" should be spelled "during"...

Comment: @Bergi - It should, and it is, in the [annotated ES5 spec](http://es5.github.com/#x4.3.6).

Comment: ...and also in the original PDF; I fixed it. @OP: Where did you copy that?

Comment: @LeilaHamon - Your excerpt which looks like it's from the spec doesn't actually match the ES5 spec... where is it from? (It's a bit closer to the ES3 spec, but your question is tagged [ecmascript-5]).

Comment: **See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8052578/what-is-an-ecmascript-native-object#8053011) for a good explanation**.

Comment: Yeah, I mistyped, it was early, so that's a valid excuse, right? :) I typed the definition of built-in object as the native object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is what [ES5 shows](http://es5.github.com/#x4.3.6):

> 4.3.6
>   native object # Ⓣ 
>   object in an ECMAScript implementation whose semantics are fully defined by this specification rather than by the host environment.
>
> NOTE Standard native objects are defined in this specification. Some native objects are built-in; others may be constructed during the course of execution of an ECMAScript program.
>
> 4.3.7
>   built-in object # Ⓣ 
>   object supplied by an ECMAScript implementation, independent of the host environment, that is present at the start of the execution of an ECMAScript program.
>
> NOTE Standard built-in objects are defined in this specification, and an ECMAScript implementation may specify and define others. Every built-in object is a native object. A built-in constructor is a built-in object that is also a constructor.

As you can see, it's different that what you've shown.

Built-in objects are native objects made available by the ECMAScript-compliant engine. For example:

- String
- Object
- Array
- Undefined
- Boolean
- etc.

A native object is, for example:

```
var obj = {};
```

Or the list shown before. Built-in objects are native.

Also, you didn't show it, but a host object is an object dependant on the environment. For example, in browsers, *the* host object is `window`. There are other host objects such as `document` or `XMLHttpRequest` though.

Comment: I think it's the other way around. The things you've listed as native objects are built-in, and an object created by a program is a native object. "built-in object... supplied by an ECMAScript *implementation*"

Comment: @JamesAllardice: A built-in object is also a native object.

Comment: @TimDown - Yes, but not the other way around, which is how I interpreted this answer originally. e.g. `String` is a built-in object (and therefore a native object). `var o = {};` is a native object, but not a built-in object.

Comment: `window` is not the only host object. It just happens also to be the global object, therefore containing properties referring to other host objects.

Comment: @TimDown I know, it's just a good example :) However I edited to please everyone!

Comment: Thanks for the answer Florian! I didn't mention host objects because there was another thread explaining the difference between native and host objects: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7614317/what-is-the-difference-between-native-objects-and-host-objects

Answer (score -3):

Native object - means implemented not in ECMAScript itself. Buiilt-in object - the one that's provided by the engine. Think Math, String and such.

Comment: It's not provided by "the environment", it's provided by the ECMAScript engine. Environment in the ES specification means that environment the engine is running in, for example a browser.