# Deleting big blobs in javascript

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, memory, internet-explorer-11

I create huge blobs in the client which the user can download as files.

The following example is just to demonstrate the issue

```js
var x= "sdfslkdfjklsdjiflskdflsdf" ; for(var i = 0; i<19;i++) x=x+x
var blob = new Blob([x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x], {
    type : "text/plain"
});
```

This will use up a lot of memory. When I'm done with the ***blob*** I would like to free up that memory.
*(I'm testing this in IE11 Edge)*

*Running this script twice will fail as no more memory can be allocated*

I've already tried setting `blob = null` or using `delete blob`, nothing happens to the memory.

How to free up the memory?

Comment: You could try "delete blob;"

Comment: All the answers are correct. Javascript is gargabe-collected, so these are your best alternatives. If you want to have more control over memory, switch to a server-side implementation and use non-managed code. Be prepared for all kinds of hell, though.

Comment: If ever you are using the `URL.createObjectURL()` method, remember to also call `URL.revokeObjectURL()`when you don't need the object url anymore, or this will take place in your memory, and won't be GCed.

Comment: @Kaiido the issue is still there even if you only paste the code in the console

Comment: @Kaiido I tried running the script and then hard-refresh (ctrl+F5), the memory is still allocated. The only thing that works is closing IE.
(Just a reminder that I'm actually running IE11 Edge)

Comment: @Feathercrown: [Nope!](http://perfectionkills.com/understanding-delete/)

Comment: Since this seems to be tightly coupled to IE, you could try calling the JScript's [CollectGarbage](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1614662/what-is-the-javascript-method-collectgarbage-when-and-why-should-it-be-used) method after setting the values null. It's not documented well, only (might) work in IE and not even recommended by MS, but I guess its worth a try.
`Blob` also seems to have a `close()` method. Not sure what's the support for that but MDN has *"Closes the blob object, possibly freeing underlying resources."* to say about it. Sounds promising to me.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are going to hit a wall here. Javascript is [garbage-collected](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Memory_Management), which means the best you can do is "unset" variables to effectively mark them for garbage-collection, *when* the browser thinks it's time.

As charming as it might seem, setting to `null` will not free the allocated memory right away, but only remove a reference -- freeing memory only possibly later, when garbage-collection actually occurs (given that no other references to the involved object exist):

```
var blobA = new Blob(...);
var blobB = blobA;
blobA = null;
console.log(blobB); // Blob, the object still exists
```

Garbage collection is automatic, and there is *no* way to predict or detect when it happens from within Javascript. There is one way to manually trigger it, however:

```
window.location.reload();
```

That's correct, doing a full reload of the whole page will trigger garbage collection, which is effectively the only way to do it AFAIK. You might want to consider this when designing your application.